# Process visualization based on data

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-charts

I am trying to use a Google spreadsheet to visualize a customer journey.

I am trying to create the following graphic:

[image]

I have created the following example spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iaza4zog4PVTpzw_6eWY8rPyQifzaRKaLNyl0AbZA3o/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggestions on how to visualize the customer journey?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 0):

It is doable but your data needs to be reorganized a bit:

**cell B16:**

```
={"Attention";
"Information";
"Lead";
"Contact";
"Sales";
"After-Sales"}
```

**cell C16:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
 VLOOKUP(B16:B21, FILTER({E2:E13, D2:D13}, B2:B13="Persona 1"), 2, 0), 
 "Website", 1), "Mailbox", 2), "Call", 3)*1)
```

**cell D16:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
 VLOOKUP(B16:B21, FILTER({E2:E13, D2:D13}, B2:B13="Persona 2"), 2, 0), 
 "Website", 1), "Mailbox", 2), "Call", 3)*1)
```

And then your chart can be like:

[image: 0]

Comment: @Kare vertical values (1, 2, 3) can't be text strings coz charts needs to run on numbers, but there is a workaround... double-click on **2** and set display color to white. then go to **Insert** > **Drawings** and add text boxes which you will overlay over the chart